# Why the first letter when I use ```onKeyDown```does not show up in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I use `react-semantic-ui` and I have an `Input`, where user types a message. I use the `onKeyDown` and then I handle it in a function in order to create some data in firebase when first letter of message is typed. The problem is that the function works after the second letter and not by the first.

Also when deleting all the letters from the message, the data in firebase get removed. But when I delete all the letters the data is still there. Then if I press delete one more time, the data gets removed.

I use a `console.log` to see the state of message, and it proves that the first letter does not get stored in the state immediately. Only after I type the second letter, I get the first in the state etc... Also with deleting...

Can anyone please explain why the first letter doesn't show up at first keydown?

Thanks

```js
handleKeyDown = () => {
    const { message, typingRef, user, channel } = this.state;

    console.log("message", message);

    if (message) {
      typingRef
        .child(channel.id)
        .child(user.uid)
        .set(user.displayName);
    } else {
      typingRef
        .child(channel.id)
        .child(user.uid)
        .remove();
    }
  };
....

        <Input
          fluid
          name="message"
          value={message}
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          // onKeyDown={e => console.log(e)}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          ...
```

Comment: because the letter has not been typed yet, try 'up' or 'oninput'

Comment: @epascarello yep! onKeyUp did the job. Thanks!